# Custom layer with two parameters function on Core ML

Tags: ios, swift, deep-learning, keras, coreml

Thanks to this great article(http://machinethink.net/blog/coreml-custom-layers/), I understood how to write converting using coremltools and Lambda with Keras custom layer. 
But, I cannot understand on the situation, function with two parameters.

```
#python
def scaling(x, scale):
    return x * scale
```

Keras layer is here.

```
#python
up = conv2d_bn(mixed,
                   K.int_shape(x)[channel_axis],
                   1,
                   activation=None,
                   use_bias=True,
                   name=name_fmt('Conv2d_1x1'))
x = Lambda(scaling, # HERE !!
           output_shape=K.int_shape(up)[1:],
           arguments={'scale': scale})(up)
x = add([x, up])
```

On this situation, how can I write `func evaluate(inputs: [MLMultiArray], outputs: [MLMultiArray])` in `custom MLCustomLayer class` on Swift? I understand just in one parameter function situation, like this,

```
#swift 
func evaluate(inputs: [MLMultiArray], outputs: [MLMultiArray]) throws {
  for i in 0..<inputs.count {
    let input = inputs[i]
    let output = outputs[i]

    for j in 0..<input.count {
      let x = input[j].floatValue
      let y = x / (1 + exp(-x))
      output[j] = NSNumber(value: y)
    }
  }  
}
```

How about two parameters function, like `x * scale`?

Full code is here.

- Converting to Core ML model with custom layer
  https://github.com/osmszk/dla_team14/blob/master/facenet/coreml/CoremlTest.ipynb
- Network model by Keras
  https://github.com/osmszk/dla_team14/blob/master/facenet/code/facenet_keras_v2.py

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `scale` is a hyperparameter, not a learnable parameter, is that correct?

In that case, you need to add `scale` to the parameters dictionary for the custom layer. Then in your Swift class, `scale` will also be inside the parameters dictionary that is passed into your `init(parameters)` function. Store it inside a property and then in `evaluate(inputs, outputs)` read from that property again.

My blog post actually shows how to do this. ;-)

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much. I'm so grad that you commented.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The `scale` is a hyperparameter. Thanks to your fruitful blog post and your code, I could solve this problem!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem on this way thanks to hollance's blog. On converting func,  in this case, in `convert_lambda`, I should have added a `scale` parameter for the custom layer.

python code(converting Core ML)

```
def convert_lambda(layer):
    if layer.function == scaling:
        params = NeuralNetwork_pb2.CustomLayerParams()

        params.className = "scaling"
        params.description = "scaling input"

        # HERE!! This is important.
        params.parameters["scale"].doubleValue = layer.arguments['scale']

        return params
    else:
        return None

coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(
    model,
    input_names="image",
    image_input_names="image",
    output_names="output",
    add_custom_layers=True,
    custom_conversion_functions={ "Lambda": convert_lambda })
```

swift code(Custom layer)

```
//custom MLCustomLayer `scaling` class
let scale: Float

required init(parameters: [String : Any]) throws {
    if let scale = parameters["scale"] as? Float {
        self.scale = scale
    } else {
        self.scale = 1.0
    }
    print(#function, parameters, self.scale)
    super.init()
}

func evaluate(inputs: [MLMultiArray], outputs: [MLMultiArray]) throws {

    for i in 0..<inputs.count {
        let input = inputs[i]
        let output = outputs[i]

        for j in 0..<input.count {
            let x = input[j].floatValue
            let y = x * self.scale
            output[j] = NSNumber(value: y)
        }
        //faster
        /*
        let count = input.count
        let inputPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>(OpaquePointer(input.dataPointer))
        let outputPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>(OpaquePointer(output.dataPointer))
        var scale = self.scale
        vDSP_vsmul(inputPointer, 1, &scale, outputPointer, 1, vDSP_Length(count))
        */
    }
}
```

Thank you.