# Is it possible to replace keras Lambda layers with native CoreML ones to convert the model?

Tags: keras, coreml, coremltools

For the first time I faced a need to convert mu keras model to coreml. This can be done via `coremltools` package,

```
import coremltools
import keras

model = Model(...) # keras

coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model,
    input_names="input_image_NHWC",
    output_names="output_image_NHWC",
    image_scale=1.0,
    model_precision='float32',
    use_float_arraytype=True,
    custom_conversion_functions={ "Lambda": convert_lambda },
    input_name_shape_dict={'input_image_NHWC': [None, 384, 384, 3]}
    )
```

However, I have two lambda layers, where the first one is depth-to-space (pixelshuffle) and another one is scaler:

```
def tf_upsampler(x):
    return tf.nn.depth_to_space(x, 4)

def mulfunc(x, beta=0.2):
    return beta*x

...

x = Lambda(tf_upsampler)(x)
...
x = Lambda(mulfunc)(x)
```

The only advice I found was as far as I understand, to use custom layer with the need to implement my layer in Swift code later. Something like this with `MyPixelShuffle` and `MyScaleLayer` to be implemented somehow as classes in XCode project (?):

```
def convert_lambda(layer):
    # Only convert this Lambda layer if it is for our swish function.
    if layer.function == tf_upsampler:
        params = NeuralNetwork_pb2.CustomLayerParams()

        # The name of the Swift or Obj-C class that implements this layer.
        params.className = "MyPixelShuffle"

        # The desciption is shown in Xcode's mlmodel viewer.
        params.description = "pixelshuffle"

        params.parameters["blockSize"].intValue = 4



        return params
    elif layer.function == mulfunc:
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47987777/custom-layer-with-two-parameters-function-on-core-ml
        params = NeuralNetwork_pb2.CustomLayerParams()

        # The name of the Swift or Obj-C class that implements this layer.
        params.className = "MyScaleLayer"
        params.description = "scaling input"

        # HERE!! This is important.
        params.parameters["scale"].doubleValue = 0.2


        # The desciption is shown in Xcode's mlmodel viewer.
        params.description = "multiplication by constant"

        return params
```

However, I found that CoreML actually has layers I need, they can be found as [`ScaleLayer`](https://apple.github.io/coremltools/coremlspecification/sections/NeuralNetwork.html#scalelayerparams) and [`ReorganizeDataLayer`](https://apple.github.io/coremltools/coremlspecification/sections/NeuralNetwork.html#reorganizedatalayerparams)

How can I use those native layers to replace lambdas in keras model? Is it possible to edit coreML protobuf for the network? Or if there are Swift/OBj-C classes for them, how they are called?

Can it be done via deleting/adding layers with `coremltools.models.neural_network.NeuralNetworkBuilder` ?

UPDATE:

I found that [keras converter](https://github.com/apple/coremltools/blob/master/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras2_converter.py) actually invokes Neural network builder to add different layers. [Builder has the layer `builder.add_reorganize_data` I need](https://github.com/apple/coremltools/blob/3a980c59e8dbf2bb81aa699730e003bcdc490ce0/coremltools/models/neural_network/builder.py). Now it's a question how to replace custom layers in the model. I can load it into builder and isnpect layers:

```
coreml_model_path = 'mymodel.mlmodel'

spec = coremltools.models.utils.load_spec(coreml_model_path)
builder = coremltools.models.neural_network.NeuralNetworkBuilder(spec=spec)
builder.inspect_layers(last=10)
```

```
[Id: 417], Name: lambda_10 (Type: custom)
          Updatable: False
          Input blobs: ['up1_output']
          Output blobs: ['lambda_10_output']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much simpler to do something like this:

```
def convert_lambda(layer):
    if layer.function == tf_upsampler:
        params = NeuralNetwork_pb2.ReorganizeDataLayerParams()

        params.fillInTheOtherPropertiesHere = someValue

        return params
    ...etc..
```

In other words, you don't have to return a custom layer if some existing layer type already does what you want.

Comment: Thanks very much. Unfortunately, I can't validate the result yet, because it's so much problems in my model during conversion. I got rid of shape mismatch error between input and first convolutional layer (the first has 3 dimensions, while conv_in expects 4) when I switched to older version 3.0  Another one was error with concatenate having single input, because in one place I have `Concatenate()([x,x])` for a reason. I fixed that by editing conversion code, but I still have new errors, now concatenate layers have mismatching shapes (whlie everything is ok in keras). It's so hard...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, seems I have found a way to go. I created a virtual environment with separate copy of coremltools and edited `_convert()` method in `_keras2_converter.py` by adding the following code:

```
 for iter, layer in enumerate(graph.layer_list):
        keras_layer = graph.keras_layer_map[layer]
        print("%d : %s, %s" % (iter, layer, keras_layer))
        if isinstance(keras_layer, _keras.layers.wrappers.TimeDistributed):
            keras_layer = keras_layer.layer
        converter_func = _get_layer_converter_fn(keras_layer, add_custom_layers)
        input_names, output_names = graph.get_layer_blobs(layer)
        # this may be none if we're using custom layers
        if converter_func:
            converter_func(builder, layer, input_names, output_names,
                           keras_layer, respect_trainable)
        else:

            if _is_activation_layer(keras_layer):
                import six
                if six.PY2:
                    layer_name = keras_layer.activation.func_name
                else:
                    layer_name = keras_layer.activation.__name__
            else:
                layer_name = type(keras_layer).__name__
            if layer_name in custom_conversion_functions:
                custom_spec = custom_conversion_functions[layer_name](keras_layer)
            else:
                custom_spec = None

            if layer.find('tf_up') != -1:
                print('TF_UPSCALE found')
                builder.add_reorganize_data(layer, input_names[0], output_names[0], mode='DEPTH_TO_SPACE', block_size=4)
            elif layer.find('mulfunc') != -1:
                print('SCALE found')
                builder.add_scale(layer, W=0.2, b=0, has_bias=False, input_name=input_names[0], output_name=output_names[0])
            else:
                builder.add_custom(layer, input_names, output_names, custom_spec)
```

The trigger is layer name. In keras I use `model.load_weights(by_name=True)` and the following marking of my lambdas:

```
x = Lambda(mulfunc, name=scope+'mulfunc')(x)

x = Lambda(tf_upsampler,name='tf_up')(x)
```

Now the model at least has layers I need:

```
[Id: 417], Name: tf_up (Type: reorganizeData)
          Updatable: False
          Input blobs: ['up1_output']
          Output blobs: ['tf_up_output']
```

Now it's time to validate on my VBox MacOS, will post what I've got.

UPDATE:

I don't see errors regarding my replaced Lambda layers, but have another one not allowing me to predict:

`Layer 'concatenate_1' type 320 has 1 inputs but expects at least 2`

I think it's related to the fact that Keras receives single input to concatenate layer which is a list of inputs. Looking how to fix this

UPDATE 2:

Tried to hotfix this by using `add_concat_nd(self, name, input_names, output_name, axis)` function of builder for my concatenate layers: got error during inference that this layer type is usupported (?!) :

```
if converter_func:
            if layer.find('concatenate') != -1:
                print('CONCATENATE FOUND')
                builder.add_concat_nd(layer, input_names, output_names[0], axis=3)
            else:
                converter_func(builder, layer, input_names, output_names,
                           keras_layer, respect_trainable)
```

`Unsupported layer type (CoreML.Specification.NeuralNetworkLayer)`

UPDATE 4:

[Found fix for this](https://github.com/apple/coremltools/issues/422), and changed the way how builder is initialized:

`builder = _NeuralNetworkBuilder(input_features, output_features, mode = mode,
                                    use_float_arraytype=use_float_arraytype, disable_rank5_shape_mapping=True)`

Now error message is gone, but I have problems with XCode version: model has version 4, while my Xcode supports 3. Will seek to update my VM.

"CoreML survival guide" pdf suggests in this case:

> `pip install -U git+https://github.com/apple/coremltools.git`
>   For example, if loading a model using coremltools gives an error such as the following, then
>   try installing the latest coremltools directly from the GitHub repo.
>
> `Error compiling model: "Error reading protobuf spec. validator error:
>   The .mlmodel supplied is of version 3, intended for a newer version of
>   Xcode. This version of Xcode supports model version 2 or earlier.`

UPDATE:

Updated from git. Have error:

No module named 'coremltools.libcoremlpython'

Looks like latest git is broken :(

[Damn, it seems I need macos 10.15 and xcode 11](https://github.com/apple/coremltools/issues/400)

UPDATE 5:

Still fighting with bug on 10.15. Found that

1. coremltools somehow deduplicates inputs to Concatenate layer, so if you have in your keras code something like `Concatenate()([x,x])` you will have concatenate layer with 1 inputs in coreml and error. To fix it I try to further modify the code above:

```
if layer.find('concatenate') != -1:
                print('CONCATENATE FOUND', len(input_names))
                if len(input_names) == 1:
                    input_names = [input_names[0],input_names[0]]
                builder.add_concat_nd(layer, input_names, output_names[0], axis=3)
```

2. [I faced this error: `input layer 'conv_in' of type 'Convolution' has input rank 3 but expects rank at least 4`]([coremltools: how to properly use NeuralNetworkMultiArrayShapeRange?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59662399/coremltools-how-to-properly-use-neuralnetworkmultiarrayshaperange) which seems to be caused by coreml making input 3-dimensional CHW, while it must be 4 NWHC (?). Currently playing with the following

```
spec = coreml_model._spec


# fixing input shape
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59765376/coreml-model-convert-imagetype-model-input-to-multiarray

spec.description.input[0].type.multiArrayType.shape.extend([1, 384, 384, 3])
del spec.description.input[0].type.multiArrayType.shape[0]
del spec.description.input[0].type.multiArrayType.shape[0]
del spec.description.input[0].type.multiArrayType.shape[0]

coremltools.utils.save_spec(spec, "my.mlmodel")
```

Getting invalid blob shape from model internals